# Unable to update ruby file owned by OS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rubygems

I'm trying to update ruby on ubuntu using `sudo gem update --system` but keep getting the error:

> Loading the rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb file caused an
> error. This file is owned by your OS, not by rubygems upstream. Please
> find out which OS package this file belongs to and follow the
> guidelines from your OS to report the problem and ask for help. I
> tried

chown'ing the entire gems library but to no avail. What can I do?

Comment: Be wary of updating Rubies you don’t control. In general it’s best to let them be updated by what “owns” them. If you’re trying to update it because of *your* Ruby needs consider using a Ruby version manager, e.g., rvm, rbenv, asdf, etc.

Answer (score 4):

This can happen if an old ruby version is created that
.rb file. Usually it is located at

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb
```

Deleting it and trying to run

```
gem update --system
```

worked for me.